# No events being displayed on my fullcalendar. (From Google Calendar)

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

I am using the JavaScript plugin 'fullcalendar' along with the google calendar module to view a google calendar on a webpage. The problem is that no events are being displayed, nor are there any accompanying error messages in the console.

The empty calendar displays fine.

I have generated the API key, and retrieved the calendar id of the calendar I want to display.

My JS is as follows:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
      console.log("Function running");
      var calendar = $('#calendar'); 
      calendar.fullCalendar({
        googleCalendarApiKey: 'my-api-key',
        events: {
          googleCalendarId: 'my-calendar-id'
        }
      });
     });
```

The head in my html is as follows:

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/gcal.js'></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
<script src='app.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='calendar.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

The reason I have so many references is because I am simultaneously using the calendar API for a slightly different part of the application. I have looked through the network tab in the chrome dev tools, attempting to identify something like a JSON, bringing event data to the site, and nothing.

I know that fullcalendar uses AJAX to update the calendar on screen, so I have tried creating a new event on my google calendar, and viewing the network tab in case I saw a change, but nothing.

The `console.log()` is running happily, so I know the js is being loaded.

I have tried going back to the older method using the gcal feed, but `$.fullcalendar.gcalFeed(url)` is no longer a function (which is fair enough). I have got the latest version of the `gcal.js` file (the V2.0 is no longer working, so there had to be minor changes to that file).

If anybody could either find out where I am going wrong, or point me in a new direction towards other things to try, I will be extremely grateful, I am pretty much out of ideas now.

### Update

Instead of using the calendar id, I am trying the feed from the calendar (by selecting the xml option under calendar settings and copying that into the JQuery instead). This gives me an error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load     https://google.com/calendar/feeds/ed.prince5769%40gmail.com/public/basic?start=2015-06-28&end=2015-08-09&_=1436196005956. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://edprince.uk' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

If I follow this url, I get what I am looking for, a load of XML, including all of the details of the events on my calendar. So I think this is the problem, that for whatever reason, I cannot load all of that data onto my website. I am now going to look into solving this

### Update #2

I have just read through this fantastic [article](https://jvaneyck.wordpress.com/2014/01/07/cross-domain-requests-in-javascript/) about the problem. There seem to be 3 ways of approaching it, using JSONP, Server-side proxy, or CORS. The author alludes to the first two solutions creating potential security vulnerabilities, and this project cannot allow for that. CORS looks like a possible route to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access a link that needs authentication.

If you try to access the same URL in a incognito window, are you receiving the same error ("404 not found")?